# Laravel 5.2 user login redirects back to login for some reason

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I have a Laravel 5.2 app and have used the artisan make:auth command. Everything was generated correctly, I changed my table name and managed to register. I then tried to login but I'm continually sent back to the login page. If I put incorrect credentials in on purpose, I get an error so I know my credentials are correct and that Laravel is communicating with the database.
I just have no idea why I keep getting back to the login page. Can anyone help? I have posted my routes below:

```
Route::auth();


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('entity/process', 'EntityController@process');
    Route::get('entity/form/{subCategoryID}/{id?}', 'EntityController@viewForm');
    Route::get('entity/delete/{id}', 'EntityController@delete');
    Route::get('/viewList/{masterCategoryID}/{subCategoryID}', 'EntityController@viewList');
    Route::get('/viewCategories', 'MasterCategoryController@viewAll');

  Route::get('/', 'MasterCategoryController@viewAll');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: Change this variable in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/login'
```

**Solution 2**: Write your own customLogout method in AuthController. Then override default logout route like this

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@customLogout');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  i tried your suggestion and still the same problem.  Is there anything else I could post on here that would help you diagnose my problem?

Comment: Solution 1 is the common way. And i don't know why there still has problem.   Take a look at solution 2

Answer (score 0):

After investigating further I found that the database ID field for my users table was null and was not set to auto increment.  I changed it to 1 and enabled auto increment then everything worked as expected.  Thanks for everyone's help.